# GruntFile.js - Syntax error in grunt-sass file dir

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to use Grunt to compile and watch my sass, I have set my gruntfile up as normal but am receiving a syntax error (apparently there is a **:** somewhere), however I cannot for the life of me find any syntax errors in my gruntfile or package.json....

Please take a look at my gruntfile and see if you can spot where I have gone wrong:

```
**Gruntfile:**
'use strict';

    // Grunt Module
    module.exports = function(grunt) {

    sass: {
        dev: {
            files: {
                'css/file.css' : 'sass/file.scss'
            }
        }
    }

    // REGISTER PLUGINS
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // REGISTER TASKS
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);

};
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "SuperFreeBingo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "matchdep": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey My Sass block looks like this:

```
 sass:   {
        module: {
            files: [{
                expand: true, src: ['/css/style.scss', 'src/css/style.scss'], ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    }
```

I think your definition is wrong